# Question migration anti-patterns: Skeptics SE

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30700/is-2-4ghz-ieee-802-11-wifi-dangerous/30702#30702) about biological effects of wifi was asked, answered, and got a lot of engagement on EE.SE, before a moderator migrated it to the Skeptics SE site.

Understandably, Skeptics have a different set of guidelines for what constitutes good questions and answers, and it's not surprising that neither answerers nor moderators here on ee.se don't know what that is.

Subsequent to the migration, the question was marked as a dupe, and most of the answers (mine included) were closed for lack of citations (a skeptics.se requirement).

In my view, it probably makes more sense to either leave such questions here, if they're on topic, or close them without migration, if they're off-topic.

Comment: Not really a good path for getting an answer. That question is clearly about fear of technology (good fit for skeptics) and not about EE design, so it should not receive any answers here and be redirected to the proper site.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Perhaps that would be true if it hadn't had any answers, but as it is, it already had several highly rated answers (disclaimer: including my own), and as with many migrations, fared poorly because of different community standards.

Comment: Having an answer or not is not a measure for offtopicness. Answering offtpoic questions should be avoided, as it encourages people to ask more offtopic questions, because they get answered anyways.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I didn't say it was - I said it shouldn't have been migrated if it was offtopic and already had several highly rated answers.

Comment: Another single handed migrating causing issues, instead of letting a five person vote occur.

Answer (score 1):

Noted.

I wasn't aware that Skeptics.SE would purge most of the answers.  If I knew, I probably wouldn't have migrated it at that mature stage.

Comment: So, why not reopen it here and undelete all of the answers?

Comment: @DaveTweed: and then close it as offtopic here?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I don't think it is off-topic. There was a good discussion of the engineering issues in the answers.

Comment: @DaveTweed: I am not sure how the kinds of answers given alters a questions offtopicness. Anyways, the question might be re-asked in a way that concentrates more on these engineering issues, and less on the "is it healthy" issue. It should be obvious to everyone who is not living behind the moon that this is quite controversial and quickly drifts into the domain of opinions, and that you can probably fak^H^Hind enough studies to support either view. Similarly, it is not an EE design issue *if* HV is deadly, others have to figure that out, and its an EE design issue to deal with what they found

Comment: I'll be honest, it should have been closed sooner. Part of that is my fault this time, now that I know that these kinds of questions can be effectively managed by the Skeptics community.